# Powershell and XML subnodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Man schemaVersion="1">
    <version>2.2</version>
    <file>
        <properties>
        …
        </properties>
        <group> 
            <properties>
        ...
            </properties>
        </group>                     
        <group>
            <properties>
        …
            </properties>       
            <group>
                <properties>
                    <items>
                        <name>test</name>
                        <description>A test</description>
                    </items>
                </properties>
            </group>
            <group>
                <properties>
                    <items>
                        <name>test2</name>
                        <description>A test field again</description>
                    </items>
                </properties>
            </group>
        </group>
    </file>
</Man>
```

I want with powershell to add one subnode(?) contain the follows:

```
    <group>
        <properties>
            <items>
                <name>test3</name>
                <description>one more field</description>
            </items>
        </properties>
    </group>
```

exactly under the test2 node so that looks like this:

```
    <group>
        <properties>
            <items>
                <name>test</name>
                <description>A test</description>
            </items>
        </properties>
    </group>
    <group>
        <properties>
            <items>
                <name>test2</name>
                <description>A test field again</description>
            </items>
        </properties>
    </group>
    <group>
        <properties>
            <items>
                <name>test3</name>
                <description>one more field</description>
            </items>
        </properties>
    </group>
```

The problem is that the "group" is being recognized as array and I'm not able to add an element to the array. I have try a lot of tricks to add element but not in the array

The code (as I said it is in very primary stage, my first concern was to get to the  with some test values.

```
$strXMLfile="c:\blabla\bla.xml";
$xml=get-content $strXMLfile;
$xmlRoot=$xml.get_DocumentElement();
$xmlnode=$xmlRoot.file.group;
$group=0;
while (!($xmlnode[$group].properties.name -eq "test node")) {
    $group++
}
$nodesGroups=$xmlnode[$group].group;
if ($nodesGroups.count -eq $null) {
    $intNewGroup=2
}   
else {
    $intNewGroup=$nodesGroups.count+1
}

#Here should be the code for the group,properties,items line creation. Partially

$newline=$xml.CreateElement("items")

#Here should be the code for the <name>. Not ready yet
```

Comment: I add a little more with from the XML to note that the outer <group> is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new last child to an existing element (type [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx)) with the [`AppendChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx) method. So rather than manipulating the array of `<group>` elements, manipulate their common parent (the `<file>` element).

Comment: Can you be little more specific because every time I was try to append a child to <file> it was under <file>.

Comment: @Alex: sorry I had misread the XML sample (aas all `group` elements under the one `file`). For this kind of manipulation you need to use some means (eg. XPath) to find a single node. At points like this PSH's wrappers/helpers can get in the way. Easier to just work with the `System.Xml` types directly. Any chance of stripping down the samples to something that is easier to work with without needing to rebuild you app ... and what is your current code?

Comment: I don't have any code because I'm testing and testing until I'm able to point the node I want.

Comment: @Alex so you have *test code* that is Work In Progress: that's what we need to see.

Comment: I put some on my question. This my primary work because I work step by step. If was able to reach adding to <group> I believe that the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can get you started:

```
 > $xml = [XML]"<Man>...</Man>"
 > $newGrp = $xml.CreateElement("group")
 > $newGrp.InnerText = "group 3"
 > $xml.Man.file.group.AppendChild($newGrp)
```

Comment: Can you clear me the first line? The three dots are something like this: $xml = [XML]"<Man><file><group></group></file></Man>" ? Because I try it and I get: Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'AppendChild'.

Comment: The `...` represents your inner XML. I actually copied what you posted into c:\temp.xml, and did a `$xml = [XML](Get-Content c:\temp.xml)`. Then it is just a matter of finding the node you want. Then you can navigate the node tree by doing things like `$xml.Man` or `$xml.Man.file`. This will return an array of XmlElements. You can do anything to them as you would a regular .Net object of the same type.

Comment: It seems that I'm closed to what I want. My first test is a bit successful. Of course I don't need just to add <group> but also the inside <properties> the inside to inside <items> and the last <name> with the value. For this example the "group 3" is going to the <group> node. So I need to create also the inner nodes also. I don't know if is possible to do it with one command (which will be super)

Comment: It is possible to just combine some of these commands like this: `$xml.Man.file.group.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("group").AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("properties")))`. Just play around until you get the ordering right. But it will probably be more manageable to do it in several commands to build up the node structures needed.

Comment: There is something that is not working. Using the above command or with split, it creates only this -> </group> and this -> <properties/>. As result when I expand the command to <name> which has some value, the <name> has as parent node the <group> as <name />

Comment: better nesting of the commands: `(($xml.Man.file.group.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("group")).AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("properties"))).InnerText = "foo")`